# Generic way to transform { a: A | undefined } to { a?: A }

Tags: typescript

I'm using a library that requires `exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true`. Unfortunately I also use other two libraries, one of which returns objects of type `{ a: string | undefined }` and the other requires `{ a?: string }`. I get compile errors along the lines of `expected a, actual undefined` because of course `{ a: undefined }` is not the same as `{ }`.

Inevitably, the objects are deeply nested so I can't easily do something like `...(a ? { a } : { })`. Ideally I'd like a generic way to recursively transform all fields from `{ a: X | undefined }` to `{ a?: X }`. Is this possible?

p.s. Casting isn't an option as I receive runtime errors. My schema library validates the structure at runtime.

Many thanks

Comment: So you are looking for something like [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) that will make types optional behind the scenes?

Comment: Yes but obviously not all properties, just those that are undefined